# Weighted average distribution

Tags: distributions, variance, inference, random-variable, lognormal-distribution

Consider I have $2$ returns time series random variables $r_{i,t}=\ln{\left(\frac{p_{i,t+1}}{p_{i,t}} \right)}\stackrel{(i.d.)}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$.

Let's now compute a *weighted average*:

$$
R_t=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{2}{w_{i,t}r_{i,t}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{2}{w_{i,t}}}
$$

- How would the distribution of $R_t$ look like if $w_{i,t}=p_{1,t}$ i.e. if we are doing a **price-weighted average**? Can we say something about $\mathrm{E}[r]$ and $\mathrm{Var}[r]$ for example?
- And if instead $w_{i,t}=w=0.5$ i.e. we are compute a **simple average**?

*Any* insight is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator in your expression for $R_t$ is the logarithm of a weighted sum of lognormal random variables.  The distribution of this quantity is complicated, but it has some known approximations (see e.g., [Cobb and Rumi 2012](http://leo.ugr.es/pgm2012/proceedings/eproceedings/cobb_approximating.pdf)).  You could generate the distribution by simulation, or rely on one of the approximation methods in the linked paper.  The logarithm of a weighted sum of lognormal random variables will be roughly (but not exactly) normally distributed.  The moments can be found by simulation, or by the [use of the characteristic function](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/38a3/9907d5af01a6340c3b6f38dce39be3be5e8a.pdf).